# materializecss, vertically offset dropdown menu content

Tags: css, materialize

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to my nav as detailed in [the docs here](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-dropdown).

By default, `.dropdown-content` is set to `top: 0;`.  And here is the default behavior:

[image]

If I change the top to `50px` in `materialize.css` it actually moves it *up* 50 pixels and sets the element style to `top: -50px`.

Here is the code:

```
.dropdown-content {
    top: 50px;
}
```

But when it renders, the element looks like this:

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 139.297px; left: 900.891px; top: -50px; height: 216px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
```

(The key being `top: -50px;)

I tested with multiple values, here is 65:

```
.dropdown-content {
    top: 65px;
}
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 139.297px; left: 900.891px; top: -65px; height: 216px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
```

(now it is `top: -65px`)

[Here's a screenshot if you care to take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrASt.png)

Why is it inverting this value?  **How can I make the dropdown so it doesn't occlude the main menu?**

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Rob, in this case the screen shot is of the debugger which clearly shows that the element is rendering `-65px` even though in the code I'm setting `65px`.  It is NOT a screenshot of code per se.  Please read posts more carefully, or ask for clarification, before flagging for closure.

Comment: Remove the image and there is no markup or code to help you with and there is the problem. Please read links I give you before responding.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please rescind your vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked it and i see the best way to do that becuase the styles comes from JS which is have special calc i have checked and if you want to avoid any fixed height maybe you will have padding or anything in the header so the best to give the `top:100%` and to use `!important` to be stronger than the JS

give the class `.dropdown-content` `top: 100% !important;`

```
.dropdown-content {
  top: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: instant fix. Thanks!

Comment: @AdelElkhodary this is a wonderful quick fix, thank you! I am curious why in earlier versions of Materialize, this worked, yet in the current version (1.0.0) the dropdowns now overlay their content over the activator.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this option has been added in Materialize v1.0.0:
https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html
via the option `coverTrigger` on instantiation. It defaults to true (must set to false to achieve desired behavior).

Comment: In contrast to the other answers this one is no workaround but a real solution. This worked for me: $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({coverTrigger: false});

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but as a workaround I added a "spacer" element to the top of the dropdown:

```
<li class="spacer"></li>

.dropdown-content {
    background: none;  //overwrites default materialzie value of white
}

.dropdown-content li > a, .dropdown-content li > span {
    background-color: white;  //needed now that the whole menu has no background
}
.dropdown-content li:hover, .dropdown-content li.active {
    background: none; //no white on hover
}

.dropdown-content li.spacer {
    min-height: 65px;  //height of the nav element
    cursor: default;  //so it doesn't look like a menu option
    opacity: 0;  //the magic
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
  <mat-menu class="abc" #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
          <div mat-menu-item  >
           11111
          </div>

               <div mat-menu-item  >
           22222222
          </div>

       </mat-menu>
```

Hope this works

Comment: A little context might be useful. What even is `mat-menu`? A polymer element or something?  I'm not using any web components.  If it's part of materializecss please link to the docs, I'm not seeing it. Basically none of this makes sense.  Sorry.